# Why Can't I connect SQL Server to my node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

I'm using the 'mssql' npm package to connect my SQL server to my node JS.
I went through a few questions, but it wasn't solved anywhere.

My SQL Server login credentials are-

```
server type : Database Engine
Server name : DESKTOP-MPF88ST\KUSHAL 
authentication : sql server authentication 
login : username 
password : password
```

and the database I wanna get is **schoolDB**
and my code goes something like this

```
const sql =require("mssql")

const config = {
        login: 'username',
        password:'password',
        server: 'localhost',
        database: "schoolDB",
        options : {
            enableArithAbort: true
        },
        port : 1433
}

sql.connect(config, (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Connected")
        }
```

I have my TCP/IP enabled and set up, SQL Server Browser enabled, but it still throws the error-

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (E:\Kushals\server\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:68:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Connection.socketError (E:\Kushals\server\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1290:12)
    at E:\Kushals\server\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1116:21    
    at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (E:\Kushals\server\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:87:14)
    at Socket.onError (E:\Kushals\server\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:100:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
      at ConnectionError (E:\Kushals\server\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
      at Connection.socketError (E:\Kushals\server\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1290:56)
      at E:\Kushals\server\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1116:21  
      at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (E:\Kushals\server\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:87:14)
      at Socket.onError (E:\Kushals\server\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:100:12)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    code: 'ESOCKET'
  }
}
```

How can I solve it ??

Comment: Your servername is `DESKTOP-MPF88ST\KUSHAL` but you specify localhost. You need to specify `server : "DESKTOP-MPF88ST\KUSHAL"`

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts tried doing that too... Didn't help. Still the exact same error....

Comment: @Preben ping DESKTOP-MPF88ST in command line and see what you get, is that a machine that you are on? how can you get exactly the same error, when you don't use localhost anymore?

Comment: I think you people are not getting it, When you start the SQL Server Management Studio, You are asked to login, there the field "Server name" is set to that value. That probably is not a real server, I pinged it, cmd said ```Ping request could not find host DESKTOP-MPF88ST\KUSHAL. Please check the name and try again.```

Comment: @KushalChowdhury You were asked to ping the machine name DESKTOP-MPF88ST, not the server instance name DESKTOP-MPF88ST\KUSHAL.

Comment: @SMor ahhh, sorry, my bad.
I pinged DESKTOP-MPF88ST, and it responded fine,

Comment: @FlashThunder IDK, but in my code, at different instances, I tried the server name to be "localhost", "DESKTOP-MPF88ST" and "DESKTOP-MPF88ST\KUSHAL", all 3, and they all returned the same error. ESOCKET.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
  login: 'username',
  password:'password',
  database: 'schoolDB',
  server: 'DESKTOP-MPF88ST\KUSHAL',
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
})

pool.connect().then(() => {
  //sample query
  pool.request().query('select 1 as number', (err, result) => {
        console.dir(result)
    })
})
```

Comment: Nahh Bro, it crashed, saying can't find module msnodesqlv8

Comment: so install it with npm?

Comment: ahh, sorry, didn't realise that was a different package.
Yes, now it's working. Thanks a lot !!

Also, can you help me find out what exactly was wrong in my code ??

Comment: with default driver you simply can't login by windows domain

Comment: @KushalChowdhury And let's not forget you had the wrong connection information as well.

Comment: @SMor which part was wrong buddy ?? the server name ??

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the TCP/IP protocol is Enabled as it is disabled by default.

**Steps:**

1. Go to Computer management
2. Under Service and Applications -> SQL Server Configuration Manager
   -> SQL Server Network configuration -> click on "Protocols for MSSQLSERVER"
3. You will see TCP/IP section (to enable right click and enable it)

Comment: I have my TCP/IP enabled, I saw it at so many places, that's why I configured it before anything, and I've mentioned that in my post as well.